# Taking letters and numbers from different fonts

Tags: fonts, symbols

Can we mix fonts?

For example:

- Letters from Palatino
- Numbers from Times New Roman
- Greek symbols from Fourier

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Text or math fonts?

Comment: for math fonts. not only "one" character but (for example) all letters.

Comment: @mert: There's no technical difference for one character or many. Every single symbol in math mode is defined separately.

Comment: i found something: this gives letters -palatino, others -times n.r. \usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{avant} 
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{OML}{pxmi}{m}{it}