# Greek characters of mathptmx

Tags: fonts

The designer prefers using mathptmx font for the book, but I really dislike its greek characters.  They are larger and bolder than non-greek characters.  Do you have any suggestion how to please both the designer and myself? :-)

[image]

Maybe you could suggest another font that looks like Times (New) Roman and does not have this "problem" with greek characters'?  Math support is essential.

Comment: It is similar: [Taking letters and numbers from different fonts](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139548/taking-letters-and-numbers-from-different-fonts)

Comment: Maybe `txfonts` or `newtxtext`/`newtxmath` is suitable.

Comment: @LeoLiu In this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59702/suggest-a-nice-font-family-for-my-basic-latex-template-text-and-math-i-am Mico does not recommend the use of `txfonts`.  `newtxtext` is perhaps the last resort, it has funny integral signs...

Comment: It is just a sort of taste sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`txfonts` is an alternative.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\begin{document}

$\vec v = \vec\omega \times \vec r$

\end{document}
```

It uses the same fonts for text, but different fonts for math (symbols, greek, etc.)

[image]

Comment: First, according to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59702/suggest-a-nice-font-family-for-my-basic-latex-template-text-and-math-i-am, `txfonts` have inconsistent font metrics.  Second, does this mean that the same letter in text and formula are different?  If so, this is unacceptable.

Comment: BTW, after including `\usepackage{txfonts}` in my document I got zillion of errors and document fails to complile to the end...

Comment: I tried `newtx`.  I love its arrows and hate everything else (integrals, sffamily) :-)

Comment: the tex-gyre-termes and tex-gyre-math-termes fonts are supposedly a times-with-maths replacement; they are opentype fonts, so require xetex or luatex to process them.  [MathTime Pro 2 Lite](http://www2.pctex.com/downloads.php?product=MTP2L) looks good -- it's intended as a sampler for the "full fonts", but is certainly usable on its own.  so there are plenty of no-charge possibilities; of the set, i've only looked at the "reduced" mathtime offering, and i liked it.

Comment: `txfonts` "inconsistencies" are problems with spacing or maths symbols; the package is notorious for hacking with other packages' territory; `newtx` is supposedly the same fonts with some "tidies" and the inconsistencies removed.

Comment: In the end, I stuck to `newtx`.  Fortunately, it has option for `cmintegrals` for classical design of integrals and is really ISO friendly (which is important to me).  And since there are non other suggestions to my question, I'll accept your answer.